# How to convert "32 bit" to number in PHP?

Tags: php

I am printing the number of rows in a DBF file and this works:

```
$content = fread($fp, 8);
$number = 0;
for ($i = 7; $i >= 4; $i--) {
  $number = $number * 256 + ord($content[$i]);
}
print $number;
```

But I am reasonably sure there is a `pack` or `unpack` command which would do the same. Is there?

Comment: What's the value of `$content`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `$content` contains an 8 byte string and you want to ignore the first 4 bytes and take the last 4 bytes as an unsigned int. If that's the case, you can use:

```
$number = unpack('L', substr($content, 4))[1];
```

Comment: He didn't say annything about Endianness so you might be using the wrong format here

Comment: `L` uses machine order, so it's a hedged bet... :) OK maybe hedged is the wrong word there. Safe? Hmm, no. Let's just say it's a guess heh.

Comment: I fixed the code. This is what I was after: `'L'`. Thanks! `'V'` also works.